# OneDrive procedure for making product live?

Tags: onedrive

I am going into the final stages for releasing my product which uses OneDrive and I was not able to find any sort of procedure for doing so online. For Dropbox I had to apply for production and get reviewed, does OneDrive have similar requirements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such process for OneDrive. No special steps need to be taken to release an app that utilizes OneDrive APIs